# What is the first interesting theorem in (insert subject here)?

Tags: examples, soft-question, big-list

In most students' introduction to rigorous proof-based mathematics, many of the initial exercises and theorems are just a test of a student's understanding of how to work with the axioms and unpack various definitions, i.e. they don't really say anything interesting about mathematics "in the wild."  In various subjects, what would you consider to be the first theorem (say, in the usual presentation in a standard **undergraduate** textbook) with actual content?

Some possible examples are below.  Feel free to either add them or disagree, but as usual, keep your answers to **one suggestion per post.**

- Number theory: the existence of primitive roots.
- Set theory: the Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder theorem.
- Group theory: the Sylow theorems.
- Real analysis: the Heine-Borel theorem.
- Topology: Urysohn's lemma.

Edit: I  seem to have accidentally created the tag "soft-questions."  Can we delete tags?

Edit #2:  In a comment, ilya asked "You want the first result *after all the basic tools have been introduced?*"  That's more or less my question.  I guess part of what I'm looking for is the first result that justifies the introduction of all the basic tools in the first place.

Comment: I wish the system was smart enough to understand that `example = examples` and `soft-question = soft-questions` (and `topos = topoi` :) ).

Comment: @Qiaochu: If there is no question with a given tag, the tag will disappear on its own within about a day. If you find two tags that should really be the same, flag the post for moderator attention with a comment explaining that the tags should be merged. @ilya: the site doesn't understand the meanings of the tags, so it would probably cause trouble if it tried to automatically merge tags. But you usually don't write the complete name of the tag anyway; you just type the first few letters and then you're shown a list of tags that match.

Comment: @Anton, the `object = objects` idea seem to be easy to implement to me -- is there an example where this merging makes no sense?

Comment: Is anyone other than me in favor of changing the word "non-trivial" to "interesting" in the title?  I, for one, would feel much less intimidated.

Comment: This question seems to have long outgrown its usefulness (and some of the more recent additions have been, IMHO, lousy). Voting to close. 

Answer (score 32):

Finite group theory:  I would say Lagrange's theorem, that the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group.  Certainly it's prior to the Sylow theorems, certainly it has content.

Comment: I was about to post that.

I should make the addendum though that while Lagrange stated his theorem in 1770, the first full proof occurred 30 years later at the same time as the first proof of the insolubility of the quintic.

Comment: LaGrange's theorem is just an application of the definition of an equivalence class.  

Comment: Fermat's last theorem is just an application of the definition of a natural number.

Comment: It is even more trival in the case in which he stated it: If a polynomial has it's n variables permuted obtaining n! formally different expressions and by manipulating it is found out that they allot to only k different polynomials, then k divides n!. 

Proof: being all the n! expressions essentially equal, they must all group up in sets of d expressions that yield the same polynomial by manipulation. Hence k=n!/d. 

I don't understand why he didn't prove it generally. Did he state it generally? Did he need it? Has someone here read Lagrange's work? 

Comment: @Marcos : "I don't understand why he didn't prove it generally". Presumably because the definition of a group was only given in the mid-19th century.

Answer (score 28):

The uncountability of the reals.  This is such a classic fact that I'm not sure how to classify it.  Set theory, perhaps.

Comment: This was due to Cantor, right? My understanding is that he was working on perfect sets when thinking about the "cardinality" of the reals (Was it even referred to as cardinality at the time?). Although the word "sets" is used, perfect sets is somewhat topological and deals with the standard topology on Euclidean space. So I don't think it's fair to classify this as a Set Theoretic theorem (or at least not as solely a Set Theoretic theorem). 

Comment: If I remember right, Cantor referred to cardinality as the "power" of a set at that time, in either German or French.  (Hazy memories of reading some of his original letters in a history-of-logic compendium once.)

Answer (score 25):

Algebraic Geometry: Bezout's Theorem.  It's also good for selling what algebraic geometry is to people who've never heard of it before.

Comment: Bezout's Theorem is a nice theorem but it is hardly surprising in its proper setting (algebraically closed field, taking into account multiplicities and points at infinity).

Comment: But it is a great motivator for schemes and cohomology:  To put projective and affine space in the same framework, you need gluing.  To get the right formulas for higher order contact, you need the scheme theoretic intersection of curves.  When you approach the theorem cohomologically, it reduces to just intersecting lines (which is a conceptually beautiful way to approach the proof).  So not only is it simple to understand, it can be used as motivation for very deep ideas.

Answer (score 25):

Euler's theorem V-E+F=2, can be regarded as a first theorem in graph theory, or in the theory of convex polytopes, and probably 0th theorem in algebraic topology and other fields.

Answer (score 24):

Algebraic topology: Fundamental group of S^1.

Comment: I'm not sure I like this one - although it can be hard to prove when you don't have much machinery, it's basically a tautology deriving from the definition of the fundamental group and not a very insightful result. I'd say the first nontrivial theorem of algebraic topology (at least on the homology side of things) is Poincaré duality - after all that was one of the things that launched the subject. Although there are easier results (Brouwer fixed point), they do not really pertain to algebraic topology itself. Considering homotopy, there should be something about homotopy groups of spheres.

Comment: Having just taught this result, I definitely agree with Qiaochu!  Sam, if you can write down a "tautological" proof of this fact, I'd like to see it!

Comment: To be precise, I suppose I mean a proof that doesn't involve homotopy lifting.

Comment: There is an "elementary proof" using complex analysis, but this should not count as an "algebraic topology" proof. So yes, I agree with Henry.

Comment: This is an important first result because now we can prove the Brouwer fixed point theorem (usually the fundamental group comes before homology right? the other things you need for that result are much more straightforward). 

Comment: This is the most important computation in algebraic topology, in my opinion.  Everything else ultimately derives from it.

Comment: If we use the boundary of a 2-simplex to model the circle $S^1$, and us the simplicial fundamental group instead, then this result is relatively tautological. However, I do not question Jeff's comment that its tractability is the basis out much other explicit computation of other homotopy and homological invariants in algebraic topology.

Comment: I don't know what "simplicial fundamental group" means...

Answer (score 24):

Knot theory: sufficiency of the Reidemeister moves.

Answer (score 24):

Commutative Algebra: The Hilbert Basis Theorem: If R is noetherian, so is R[x].

Answer (score 23):

Ring theory: If R is a UFD, then so is R[x].

Comment: For ring theory, I prefer R noetherian implies R[x] is.  The Hilbert Basis Theorem.

Comment: Post this as a separate answer so that it can get voted independently.

Answer (score 22):

Category theory: The Yoneda lemma.

Comment: I thought about that, but I think category theorists would consider the Yoneda lemma trivial.  Not to say that it's easy to understand, but it does follow directly from the category axioms.

Comment: I think I'm only now getting where you're going. You want *the first result after all the basic tools have been introduced*?

Comment: Though Yoneda's lemma isn't non-trivial, I feel like understanding its significance is definitely a non-trivial step. Schur's lemma in representation theory and Nakayama's lemma in algebra have a similar feel to them. They're pretty trivial to prove, but can take a while to really grok them.

Comment: I think Anton said what I wanted to get across: the Yoneda lemma itself isn't non-trivial, but the philosophy of it is.

Comment: I agree with Anton and Harrison. It really isn't that much of a theorem (to prove that is) but understanding all consequences is non-trivial. Same goes for Schur's lemma, which is absolutely trivial to proof, but fundamental to the subject.

Comment: Maybe it's more correct to say that Yoneda is the last trivial theorem?

Answer (score 22):

Quadratic reciprocity feels to me like a "first nontrivial statement" without an obvious branch of mathematics. Not number theory -- there are things like the infinitude of the primes, and "algebraic number theory" doesn't seem quite right either...

Comment: The first nontrivial statement in class field theory?

Answer (score 22):

Differential equations: Picard's theorem on existence and uniqueness.

Answer (score 21):

Graph theory: necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of an Eulerian walk/cycle

Answer (score 20):

Linear algebra: rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Although of course, this is just a categorification of the corresponding statement for finite sets...

Comment: Do you mean the statement that a set is the union of the preimages of the image elements under a map?  I think both statements are categorifications of the existence of addition, but linear categorifications are intrinsically more powerful.

Comment: You could say that the rank nullity theorem is a direct consequence of the fact that all modules over fields are free (and hence projective). This may be a warped way of looking at things but I have to admit, thats how I remember it now :)

Comment: I've been teaching some linear algebra this term. It's really satisfying seeing pupils realise just what a powerful tool this theorem is. (Powerful, that is, in the context of first year lin alg...)

Comment: I think that various theorems about bases (every two bases have the same cardinality, every linearly independent set can be extended to a basis, and so on) are nontrivial and certainly come earlier. Why non-trivial? Because they may fail for modules over other rings, even if the module is free (but the ring may be noncommutative) or for f.g. modules over commutative rings (maximal linearly independent systems may have different cardinality, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30066/cardinality-of-maximal-linearly-independent-subset)

Answer (score 19):

Number theory:  Different undergraduate textbooks approach the subject differently, of course. But the irrationality of the square root of 2 and the infinitude of primes are contentful theorems that are certainly very early *historically*, and also very early in at least some textbook treatments of the subject.

Comment: I have to admit when I say "number theory" I always think "in the sense of Gauss."  The infinitude of the primes is a better candidate now that I think about it.

Comment: Perhaps you could even argue that the irrationality of the square root of 2 and the infinitude of primes are the first nontrivial theorems in mathematics as a whole.  The Pythagorean theorem  seems to be another candidate in this direction.

Comment: Probably Pythagorean before "sqrt(2) is irrational".  Without a^2 + b^2 = c^2 with a = b = 1, we have no reason to consider sqrt(2) in the first place.

Answer (score 19):

Probability theory: the Central Limit Theorem?

Comment: I would consider the law of large numbers non-trivial, and that was covered in my probability courses long before the CLT.  

Answer (score 19):

Social choice theory: [Arrow's Impossibility Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem).

Comment: This is the first time I’ve heard of Social Choice Theory, which is why I have to upvote this answer.

Answer (score 16):

Functional Analysis: the Hahn-Banach Theorem.

Answer (score 16):

Theory of Computation: The halting problem

Set Theory: Cardinality of a set is strictly less than its powerset

Not sure which field (one might learn it in an intro real analysis course): Reals are uncountable

Complexity theory: The Time and Space Hierarchy theorems

One might learn these results in different courses, but they're all the same beautiful idea: Cantor's diagonalization.

Answer (score 14):

Functional analysis: the open mapping theorem.

Comment: there's a case for saying "Banach-Steinhaus theorem" or "uniform boundedness", which are somehow the deepest part of (the proof of) the open mapping theorem. But yes, this one gets a vote from me.

Answer (score 13):

Computer science: sort requires `n * log n`

Comment: Nitpick: Comparison based sort is \Omega(n*log n).

Comment: Comparison as in bubble sort (n*n) or as in some other sort? I mean *any sorting algorithm requires asymptotically at least* `C * n * log n`.

Comment: That is only true for comparison-based sorting algorithms. There are non comparison-based sorting algorithms if your data consists of numbers or alphabets, or things like that. For example, radix sort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Comment: Well, it's simply about the way you define your problem; other sorts have input defined in a different way. "Hence, radix sort does not really beat O(n log n) time, it only appears to do so because the range of keys is implicitly limited by the size of k." (from wikipedia)

Comment: Yijie Han http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgor.2003.09.001 has an algorithm for sorting natural numbers that takes time O(n log log n). So it really depends on the class of sorting algorithms.

Any *comparison sort* needs at least $\log_2 n! > c n \log n$ *comparisons*.

Answer (score 13):

Symplectic Geometry: Darboux's theorem

Comment: Does this predate Liouville's theorem that Hamiltonian flows are symplectomorphisms (according to wikipedia he's only attributed for the volume preserving part)? Liouville was about 30 years older.

Answer (score 13):

Finite group representation theory: the fact that the irreducible characters form a basis for the class functions.

Answer (score 13):

Noncommutative ring theory: The Artin-Wedderburn Theorem.

A ring R is semisimple if and only if it is isomorphic to a finite direct product of matrix rings over division rings.

Comment: Being R a unital ring.

Answer (score 13):

Although the Gauss-Bonnet theorem was cited for differential geometry of surfaces, I really think that the **first** striking result in this subject is Gauss's [Theorema Egregium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorema_egregium), which is not obvious from the definition of Gaussian curvature (which makes explicit reference to the ambient space). But the Gauss-Bonnet theorem is certainly the first really deep theorem one encounters in differential geometry.

Comment: Theorema Egregium is certainly very deep! Without Theorema Egregium to back it up, the Gauss-Bonnet theorem isn't very meaningful, and of course, it comes later.

Answer (score 12):

operator algebras: the Gelfand transform is an isomorphism for commutative $C^*$-algebras.

Answer (score 12):

Riemann Surfaces: Riemann-Roch Theorem

Answer (score 9):

Combinatorics: the nth Catalan number is (2n choose n)/(n+1)

Answer (score 8):

Algebraic topology: Poincaré Duality

Answer (score 7):

Euclidean geometry: a triangle on a semicircle has a right angle.

Answer (score 7):

Additive combinatorics: Roth's theorem (that a dense subset of $\{1,2,...,N\}$ contains an arithmetic progression of length 3). It's extraordinary how much of the subject opens up once one has seen just this theorem proved, and it can be done quite easily from first principles.

Comment: Now, isn't Cauchy-Davenport already quite interesting?

Answer (score 6):

Finite geometry: The [Bruck-Ryser-Chowla Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruck%E2%80%93Chowla%E2%80%93Ryser_theorem). If a finite projective plane of order q exists and q is congruent to 1 or 2 (mod 4), then q must be the sum of two squares.
 
BRC also has the distinction of being the la(te)st non-trivial theorem in finte geometry/design theory, as it's been the strongest result on existence of projective planes/symmetric designs for a given class of orders q for the past 60 years.

Comment: Excluding, of course, the result of Lam, Thiel and Swiercz on the plane of order 10.  In combinatorial design theory more generally, there are certainly other non-trivial results.

Comment: I agree. I was trying to keep the post short and did not want to put in too much. Perhaps a minor edit is in order.

Comment: I remember thinking this was a really beautiful theorem when I saw it as an undergrad. I haven't thought about it for a while, thanks for reminding me :)

Answer (score 6):

In mathematical logic, Gödel's incompleteness theorem.

Comment: I would think of Completeness or Compactness of first order logic as a more reasonable answer. Incompleteness is interesting, but it feels more like a side branch of the theorem tree than the main trunk (whatever that means).

Comment: I think it's a reasonable answer, and I don't agree at all it is a side branch, since it applies to *every* part of mathematics (as developed by humans, anyway). I think completeness and compactness are also reasonable answers, but we actually got to incompleteness first in my courses, so...

Comment: Incompleteness was used as the motivation for the study of completeness and compactness in the courses I took.

Comment: My comment about the tree is that Godel's Incompleteness Theorem just doesn't get used in logic that much. Most people see it early because it has a high "Gee Whiz" factor, which makes it a good advertisement for logic.

Comment: I don't know about that.  We use the classes of large cardinals to measure consistency strength, and we need Gödel II to establish that those strengths really are different.

Answer (score 6):

Homotopy Theory: the Hopf Fibration?

Comment: That's not a theorem.

Comment: There is a theorem there (more than one, in fact), e.g. "$\pi_3(S^2)$ is an infinite cyclic group generated by the class of the Hopf fibration".

Answer (score 6):

Differential Geometry (of surfaces, say): the Gauss-Bonnet theorem.

Comment: Certainly non-trivial, but comes after Theorema Egregium (oops... I've already left an equivalent comment at Theorem Egregium entry).

Answer (score 6):

In *analytic* number theory: Euler's proof of the infinitude of primes, using the divergence of the harmonic series.

Comment: So, not Euclid's proof, then?

Comment: See the word in italics. :)

Comment: Did it not used to say Euclid?  I can't believe I made that mistake :)

Answer (score 5):

Algebraic number theory: Hilbert 90.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you consider "rings of integers are Dedekind domains" to be trivial?

Comment: No, certainly not trivial, though simple, and a good answer to the original question indeed.

Comment: On the other hand, the same applies to your examples of topology and group theory imho.

Answer (score 5):

Points on an elliptic curve form an abelian group, accredited to Fermat.

This should appear as an example when one introduces group theory. One can easily state many non-trivial facts, like the rational points form a finitely generated subgroup, whose torsion is known (Mazur), and whose rank is the subject of Birch-Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture. (That would also be a nice example of the classification theorem of finitely generated abelian groups)

Comment: I'd call this an example in group theory but a theorem in algebraic geometry.  

Comment: I actually did attend a short class about the classification theorem for finite abelian groups which discussed Mordell's Theorem on the last day.

Comment: How about nominating Mordell's theorem (finite generation of $E(\mathbb{Q})$ for the first non-trivial theorem in arithmetic algebraic geometry instead? 

Answer (score 5):

Poset theory:  Dilworth's theorem.

Answer (score 5):

In geometric probability: Buffon's noodle (and needle).

Answer (score 5):

Rings with polynomial identities (PI rings): The Amitsur Levitzki's theorem
http://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/the-amitsur-levitski-theorem-for-a-non-mathematician/

Answer (score 5):

Math/Number Theory: $\mathbb{Z}$ is an Euclidean domain..PID .. UFD

Linear Algebra: Every vector space has a basis and every two basis have the same cardinal.

Answer (score 5):

The first interesting theorem in Differential Algebra is...

Liouville´s condition for integration of elementary functions in finite terms.

Answer (score 5):

Harmonic Analysis: Plancherel's theorem

Answer (score 5):

Two fields, one first nontrivial theorem:

**Graph theory:** Hall's marriage theorem.

**Majorization theory:** Birkhoff's theorem that the set of all doubly symmetric matrices is the convex hull of the permutation matrices.

Answer (score 4):

**Complex analysis**: Riemann mapping theorem.

(Easier candidates include: Liouville's theorem, Cauchy's integral formula, Picard theorems.)

Comment: I didn't see your answer before I posted mine (Hadamard's theorem). I guess Hadamard's factorization theorem and Riemann's mapping theorem are pretty much independent, so either one could potentially be the "first nontrivial theorem." :-)

Comment: At least for me, taking this course as an undergraduate, it was the Cauchy integral formula for sure. 

Comment: he Cauchy integral formula may be under-appreciated these days because we've moved it up early in the curriculum. We think it's elementary because it's presented early on. But historically it came after much of the material now in a complex analysis course. It was moved up precisely because it is so powerful and makes the proofs of other theorems easier.

Answer (score 4):

The representation theory of compact groups: The Peter-Weyl Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Lie Algebras: Simple Lie algebras can be recovered from their Dynkin diagrams via Serre relations. (Maybe you can argue that PBW is really the first non-trivial fact)

Comment: I would suggest Weyl complete reducibility.

Comment: I agree it's non-trivial if you try to prove it purely algebraically, but the proof using the unitary trick on the associated simply connected compact group is pretty easy to digest.

Comment: The construction of a compact form requires nontrivial amounts of structure theory. In fact, I conjecture that most people who know about unitary trick have never seen a complete proof. Fortunately, algebraic arguments based on Casimir allow one to bypass these complications.

Answer (score 3):

Commutative algebra:  primary decomposition.

Comment: Really?  Atiyah-Macdonald, at least, doesn't seem to care about primary decomposition.

Comment: It's chapter 4 in A-M according to Google books; the previous chapters are on rings, modules, and localization, and are (if I remember correctly, or guess correctly based on the topic list) basically definition-oriented.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the introduction.  The beginning of the chapter: "In the modern treatment, with its emphasis on localization, primary decomposition is no longer such a central tool in the theory.  It is still, however, of interest in itself and in this chapter we establish the classical uniqueness theorems."

Comment: I'd argue for Nakayama on the same grounds as the Yoneda lemma, but again that's of a rather different nature.

Answer (score 3):

Analysis/Topology. The closed interval [a,b] is compact.

Comment: Not with the metric definition "compact" = "closed and bounded", because then it's obvious. Perhaps you mean the Heine–Borel theorem, but that was already listed in the original question.

Comment: lhf, the unit ball of an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is closed and bounded, but not compact. 

Answer (score 3):

**Theoretical computer science** or **combinatorics** or **algorithmics**: The diamond lemma.

Some days ago, while giving a seminar talk about Clifford algebras, I realized that Lawson-Michelson has a flawed proof that the canonical inclusion of a vector space in its own Clifford algebra is indeed injective (unfortunately, not until I had written this proof on desk). Most other literature gives ugly proofs using orthogonalization. Fact is, this injectivity works in a much more general context (namely, it works for any module over a commutative ring with $1$), where of course there needs not be any orthogonalization. And it is easily proven using the diamond lemma. A similar assertion for Weyl algebras is also clear from the diamond lemma, and so is the Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witt theorem (which is proven in intricate and opaque ways in most of literature). Maybe the problem is that geometers don't know enough computer science?

Answer (score 3):

Algebra: Classification of finite abelian groups

Answer (score 2):

Combinatorics: counting the number of derangements of [n].

Comment: I'm not at all convinced that this is the best answer, but after a few minutes of scratching my head, I turned to an old undergraduate textbook. Six chapters in, this is the first proven result that seems to qualify.

Comment: I think I would disagree, since counting derangements is just a standard application of inclusion-exclusion, which is pretty trivial.

Comment: Combinatorics doesn't really fall under the purvey of this question, since it's both relatively non-axiomatic and highly non-linear.  And for what it's worth, I consider inclusion-exclusion highly nontrivial, at least conceptually (as Mobius inversion).

Comment: I think this answer is reasonable.  But this implicitly requires that permutations be one of the first objects you look at.  As Qiaochu has pointed out, we don't necessarily have to make this choice.

Answer (score 2):

Banach algebras: Gelfand's proof of the Wiener lemma for l<sup>1</sup>(**Z**)

Comment: (I suppose someone will point out that this rests on the Gelfand-Mazur theorem, but I maintain that Wiener's lemma is more arresting and grabs the attention better - hence is more "interesting" in that sense. Obviously the Gelfand-Mazur theorem lies deeper and is in that sense more "interesting")

Answer (score 2):

Nonlinear programming/Optimization: The [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) conditions

Answer (score 2):

In real analysis, I would say The intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Measure theory: the Hahn decomposition theorem.

If one were to attempt to simply union together all positive sets, one may end up with an uncountable union, which is thus not necessarily measurable.  The fact that you can decompose the space into a positive and negative set is therefore a little surprising.  The constructions in the proof of this theorem are typically delicate.

Answer (score 2):

**Homological algebra:** the cup product in (co)homology is graded commutative.

Is there a good reference for proofs of this in different cohomological theories? I know two proofs in simplicial homology and one proof in Hochschild cohomology... but I am far from seeing the relation between all these cup products.

Comment: Do you mean that everything before cup product is trivial? Really?

Comment: The question is about "interesting", not about "nontrivial". "Interesting", for me, means a theorem which gets us more than we could have expected by looking at the condition and thinking about it for a while. I don't think the long exact sequences, the homotopic equivalence of resolutions and the basic properties of cup (not the commutativity) would fall under this, even if they are certainly not easy to come up with from scratch.

Comment: You'll find in the arXiv a little note of mine which proves the commutativity of cup products in lots of cohomology theories.

Comment: To be precise, the question asks for "the first theorem... with the actual content". Long exact sequence and homotopic equivalence of resolutions may not pass your muster, but what about, say, Hilbert's syzygy theorem? There are whole books on homological algebra that do not touch cup products(Gelfand-Manin is one, if I remember correctly).

Comment: Mariano: I know, but I don't know derived categories (still).

Comment: Victor: that's commutative algebra for me. I was talking about the skeleton of homological algebra, not the various concrete cases.

Comment: Well, cup product in cohomology is algebraic topology, then. I am not sure what to make of your distinction between "skeleton" and "various concrete cases".

Comment: No, it can be defined purely algebraically in Hochschild-like theories.

Answer (score 2):

Game Theory:

A zero-sum 2x2 (two person) matrix game which has no dominating strategy has an optimal mixed strategy, and the game is fair (0 expected value) if the determinant of the payoff matrix (say from the row player's point of view) is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Real Analysis: The function $t \mapsto \exp(it)$, defined by a certain power series, is periodic with a period of about 6.4.

Comment: The second theorem is that 6.3 is closer.

Answer (score 1):

Algebraic geometry: points are prime ideals.

Comment: I would call this more a modification of the definition of "point" than anything else.  But I would agree that something like "the Nullstellensatz" is a great answer here.

Comment: I feel like non-trivial fact 1 is that "points are maximal ideals", and then non-trivial fact 2 is that "oh wait, points should really be prime ideals", followed by contemplating the nature of what a point is.

Comment: Mm, depends on your taste certainly. But, ok, let's define the point geometrically as the minimal subscheme then it's a theorem.

Comment: I feel like history tells us that "points are maximal ideals" is non-trivial fact 1, then perhaps the Nullstellensatz is fact 2, and then... and then "oh wait, points are really prime ideals" is non-trivial fact \omega. Followed by \omega + 1, and so on. But of course history is often wrong.

Comment: I feel like non-trivial fact 1 is that "points are maximal ideals" <== this is exactly Euclid's "a point is what has no parts". Though I'm not quite saying this makes it trivial...

Comment: It is certainly a non trivial result for commutative $C^*$ algebras and not only a new definition! Here, maximal ideals are exactly the nonzero prime ideals.

Answer (score 1):

Fractional or arbitrary order calculus - The derivation of the known equation by Louisville to show that classical calculus is a special case of fractional calculus, in a paper written in 1832.

This was not a rigorous proof ala Euclid, but it was important to prove a concept that was known since at least 1695.

Answer (score 1):

**3-manifolds**, existence and uniqueness of decomposition into irreducible pieces in the connected sum (Kneser, Milnor-Wallace)

Answer (score 1):

Differential Geometry: Rank Theorem

Answer (score 1):

Ergodic theory: Poincare's recurrence theorem
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Complex analysis: Hadamard's factorization theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Symbolic dynamics: There is a unique minimal right resolving presentation for an irreducible sofic shift.

Answer (score 0):

Order / Lattice Theory (?): The Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem (BPI). 
It is strictly weaker than the axiom of choice but equivalent to Tychonovs theorem (EDIT: of course the version where the spaces are *Hausdorff*, compact) therefore underlying all of functional analysis.

Comment: Tychonoff's theorem is **equivalent** to choice. Perhaps you mean Tychonoff for compact *Hausdorff* spaces?

Comment: That is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

In algebraic number theory, at least in terms of a serious interesting result with a difficult proof, I'd say the Tchebotarev Density Theorem.

More elementary would be Sum(ef)=n and/or properties of decomposition and inertia groups. Also Dirichlet's Unit Theorem, depending on what order you work in.

In analytic number theory, I would say the Prime Number Theorem, at least if we're looking for the first difficult, interesting result.

Comment: I might add the finiteness of the class number. Or if you're looking for theorems which show how the machinery can be used, I would add some of the elementary Diophantine problems which can be solved using finiteness of the class number.

Answer (score 0):

In Euclid's *Elements* the first proposition is the construction of the equilateral triangle.  An interesting result, perhaps, but also important as a beginning of an explanation of what "proof" shall mean.

Answer (score 0):

ML：Gödel incompleteness theorem

Answer (score 0):

Plane geometry, either Euclid Bk 1, Prop 47 (Pythagoras' theorem), or the nine-point circle theorem.  I can't decide.

Answer (score 0):

The first interesting theorem in Non Euclidian Geometry is...

This isn´t a proof, but it´s the object of the study fisically represented:
paper model of hyperbolic plane ([by Bill Thurston](http://books.google.com/books?id=Lurp6nB4LtQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=shape+space&hl=es#v=onepage&q=&f=false)). I´m lovin it!
...and of course, the models of Klein and of Poincaré of hyperbolic plane (My favorite is the half plane)

Answer (score 0):

Linear Algebra: The Principal Axis Theorem. Quadratic forms over reals have a signature, i.e. after a change of coordinates, are of the form $(x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2)-(y_1^2+\cdots + y_m^2)$.

Comment: This is called Sylvester's Rule.

Comment: Sylvester's Law, rather.

Comment: I'd say it shares its place with Cayley-Hamilton.

Answer (score 0):

Fourier Theory:The Fast Fourier Transform

Answer (score -1):

Number Theory: Kronecker-Weber (Every abelian extension of Q is contained in a cyclotomic extension.)

Comment: This is a wonderful theorem but it's hardly the first interesting theorem in Number Theory.

Comment: It is really up to personal taste :) I understand there are other more elementary ones like finiteness theorems for class number, etc. But I really find Kronecker-Weber the first interesting thing to me. Your favorite interesting theorem?

Comment: Mine is Fermat's criterion for a number to be expressed as the sum of two squares.

Answer (score -1):

```
  fundamental theorem of algebra
  fundamental theorem of calculus
```

Comment: In what subject is the fundamental theorem of algebra the first interesting theorem?

Comment: Complex analysis?

Answer (score -5):

Number Theory -- [Mordell-Weil Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mordell-WeilTheorem.html)

Comment: That's the *first* interesting/non-trivial result in Number Theory? 