# Maximum cardinal of a set of linearly independent vectors in a module

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules

A student asked me this, and I can't believe I never knew the answer to this.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and $M$ be an $R$-module.

1. If $M$ has a set of $n$ linearly independent vector for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, does that necessarily imply that $M$ has an infinite set of linearly independent vectors?
2. More generally, if $\kappa$ is the minimum cardinal such that there is no set of cardinality $\kappa$ of linearly independent vectors. Must $\kappa$ be always a successor cardinal?

Comment: Now I won't be able to sleep until I know the answer. :-(

Comment: To start with, what are the standard examples/constructions of modules having maximal independent sets of different cardinalities?  [This question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/30066/17064) suggests that they are not easy to come by (I didn't look at the Lazarus paper, but "the examples (…) are highly nontrivial" doesn't seem too promising).

Comment: The answer to 1 seems to be obviously yes. Let $\kappa$ be the cardinality of the set of all linearly independent vectors of $M$ and suppose $\kappa$ is finite. Then $\kappa\in\mathbb{N}$ contradicting that $M$ also has $\kappa+1$ linearly independent vectors. As for 2, I'm not a set theorist...

Comment: @j0equ1nn: "the set of all linearly independent vectors" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: there is an explicit example [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33294/linearly-independent-subsets-of-a-free-module) which is also a free module; however we know our example cannot be free.

Comment: @j0equ1nn: number 2 is basically the same as number 1: must there always be a set of linearly independent vectors of maximum cardinality.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Totally, I missed the whole point of the question. I was thinking more like, cardinality of a basis, but any candidate for an $M$ satisfying the question would not have a basis.

Comment: (2) is answer negatively with $\kappa=\aleph_0$. Still, it would be interesting to ask (2) assuming that $\kappa>\aleph_0$. (And at the other extreme, ask whether every $\kappa$ can be achieved, or even whether there exists $R$ over which every $\kappa$ can be achieved.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Question 1. has a negative answer.

Denote $A := \{(i,j) \in \mathbb{N}^2, j\leq i\}$ and $S := \{$finite subsets of A with at least 2 different first coordinates$\}$. Define the ring $$R := \mathbb{F}_2[t_s: s \in S]\,/\,\big(t_{s_1}t_{s_2}: s_1,s_2 \in S\big),$$ and the $R$-module
$$M := \bigoplus_{(i,j) \in A}Rm_{ij}\,/\,\left(t_s\sum_{(i,j)\in s}m_{ij}: s \in S\right).$$

For example, $s_0=\{(1,1),(2,1))\} \in S$ and $t_{s_0}(m_{11}+m_{21})=0.$

Then for each $m$, the subset $\{m_{m1},..m_{mm}\} \subset M$ is a linearly independent subset of size $m$.

Suppose that $(x_k)_{k\in K} \subset M$ is a linearly independent family and let us show that $K$ is finite.
Denote $T := (t_s: s \in S)R$; this is a non-zero ideal of $R$.

1. Write $x_k = \Sigma r_{ij}^{(k)}m_{ij}$. Then $\{r_{ij}^{(k)}(0)\} \neq \{0\}$: otherwise $Tx_k=0$.
2. $\{x_k\}$ is linearly independent mod $T: \Sigma r_kx_k \in TM \Rightarrow \Sigma t_{s_0}r_kx_k =0 \Rightarrow t_{s_0}r_k=0$ all $k \Rightarrow r_k \in T$ all $k$.
3. $\exists m$ such that $\{x_k\} \subset \sum_nRm_{mn}$ mod $T$: otherwise $\bigcup_k\{(i,j):r_{ij}(0) \neq 0\}$ has at least 2 different first coordinates and some $t_s$ kills some $x_k$ or some $x_{k_1}+x_{k_2}$.
4. $\#(K) \leq m: \dim_{\mathbb{F}_2}\sum_nRm_{mn}$ mod $T = m$.